# R: check multiple variables using 'for' loop and 'case_when.'

Tags: r, for-loop, case-when

I have a dataset DT as below:

category: number 1-9
xxx, yyy, zzz: binary (0,1)

```
category xxx yyy zzz
8         1   0   0
1         0   0   0
4         0   1   1
9         0   0   1
8         0   1   0
```

I would like to check multiple conditions using 'for' loop and 'case_when.'
So, I wish the data shows at the end

```
category xxx yyy zzz result_xxx result_yyy result_zzz
8         1   0   0       8           0          0
1         0   0   0       0           0          0
4         0   1   1       0           4          4 
9         0   0   1       0           0          9 
8         0   1   0       0           8          0
```

To do it, I wrote a code below:

```
condition.vars <- c("xxx", "yyy", "zzz")

for(i in condition.vars){
  browser()
  DT <- DT[, condition:= case_when(
    ([[i]] == 1 & category ==1) ~ 1,
    ([[i]] == 1 & category ==2) ~ 2,
    ([[i]] == 1 & category ==3) ~ 3,
    ([[i]] == 1 & category ==4) ~ 4,
    ([[i]] == 1 & category ==5) ~ 5,
    ([[i]] == 1 & category ==6) ~ 6,
    ([[i]] == 1 & category ==7) ~ 7,
    ([[i]] == 1 & category ==8) ~ 8,
    ([[i]] == 1 & category ==9) ~ 9,
    TRUE ~ 0
  )]
  setnames(DT, "condition", paste0("result", i))
   
}
```

And as you expect, it does not work. 
Would you please help me to correct my code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need a `for` loop or `case_when`. If you have a dataframe you can simplify this as :

```
condition.vars <- c("xxx", "yyy", "zzz")
DT[paste0('result_', condition.vars)] <- DT$category * DT[condition.vars]

#  category xxx yyy zzz result_xxx result_yyy result_zzz
#1        8   1   0   0          8          0          0
#2        1   0   0   0          0          0          0
#3        4   0   1   1          0          4          4
#4        9   0   0   1          0          0          9
#5        8   0   1   0          0          8          0
```

If `DT` is `data.table` you can do :

```
library(data.table)
DT[, paste0('result_', condition.vars):= category * .SD,.SDcols = condition.vars]
```

Comment: Thank you @Ronak Shah. somehow the first does not work but the second suggestion works! I also need to develop seeing data from many perspectives. can I ask you one more? if 'category' was not number but the character, then wouldn't I need to use "case_when"?

Comment: The first one is for dataframes and since you have datatable the second answer works. I would still not use `case_when` for characters, there are other ways with `lapply` that  can be used if you have characters. You can have lot of characters of any length. Writing each condition one by one with `case_when` is not feasible here.

Answer (score 0):

We can use `tidyverse`

```
library(dplyr)
DT %>% 
     mutate(across(c(xxx, yyy, zzz), ~ 
                category * ., .names = "result_{.col}"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a `data.table` option

```
setDT(df)[,
  c(
    df,
    setNames(category * .SD, paste0("result_", names(.SD)))
  ),
  .SDcols = xxx:zzz
]
```

which gives

```
   category xxx yyy zzz result_xxx result_yyy result_zzz
1:        8   1   0   0          8          0          0
2:        1   0   0   0          0          0          0
3:        4   0   1   1          0          4          4
4:        9   0   0   1          0          0          9
5:        8   0   1   0          0          8          0
```